# Is there a way to place macOS title bars at the bottom of the window

Tags: macos

## Is there a way to place macOS title bars at the bottom of the window

### Specification

In macOS, every window that is not in full screen mode has a title bar at its top. This title bar contains the name of the window and the close button etc.

It would be nice if the title bar can be placed at the bottom of the window instead.

### Inspiration

Recent versions of Firefox allows users to place their tab bars at the bottom of the screen. Recent versions of Safari on iOS forces users to have their tab bars at the bottom of the screen.

### Usefulness

If you work with a laptop, it actually makes sense to have decorators like title bars at the bottom of the screen so the main content you read is high up and your sight can move upwards a bit. This way, you can save you neck a little bit.

Comment: window titlebars are part of macOS's window manager (Aqua) design choice by Apple and only Apple can decide if they wish to do such thing by delivering this kind of feature in a system update  as there isn't any official way of modifying the window manager's behavior (I suspect that this will not happen anytime soon since Apple's way of doing things is to make decisions best for the majority, and  the ones who have similar needs as you is more of the minority since most people aren't complaining, thus Apple will not likely to include this sort of feature)

Comment: btw you may have better luck with linux as you can choose a window manager that allows such feature (or for example i3 which allows you to remove window title bars completely :))

Comment: On Mac bottom of screen is usually containing the Dock. So having also windows title may be confusing.